# jquery find and replace for multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry I am just really starting to get into javascript and I can't nail down the syntax.

Here is my script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('div[align="right"][style="margin-right:15px;"]').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('align')
        $(this).removeAttr('style');
        $(this).addClass('homepagecontent2');
    });
});
```

Basically I just want to find every div with `align="right"` and `style="margin-right:15px;"` and then remove the `align` and `style` and add the class.

It works fine when I just look for `align="right"` but when I add the second element into the equation it breaks.

Comment: Do the elements you're attempting to select have the inline style attribute with the exact value `margin-right:15px;`?

Comment: Step 1: Remove inline styles.

Comment: Remove inline styles... WOULD LOVE TO.  Company paid 400K for a CMS that we can't even edit the homepage.  Everything is layered in divs and tables... And all of the widths are set to 800-900 and the uppers want it 1200.  So I have to edit a lot of the style stuff via js.  And yes the exact value is margin-right:15px; - I will probably need a very similar script many more times.  The CMS provider (code is 10 year old ASP) thought it would be wise to have inline styles EVERYWHERE even though they have 50 clients all on the same stuff that we cannot touch.

Comment: @DavidMoore Wow. Good luck to you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is better to filter elements by CSS style:

```
$("div[align='right']").filter(function() {
    return $(this).css("margin-right") === "15px";
}).removeAttr("align style").addClass("homepagecontent2");
```

Comment: Thank you - that is perfect.  Let me ask a couple questions - do you know of a good website that shows syntax for css/attributes?  Also I have a page load question - I am setting homepagecontent2 to display: none.  But for a split second you can see the contents.  Is that an issue with the location of css or js?  I can't tell the js to display: none because my coworkers who can't even open a js file without exploding might need to edit it in the future.

Comment: +1 for using `.css`, making this a more reliable solution than the `*=` selector I thought off. Nice one @Vision.